# Mostrar en un textbox la Qr c#.net

Tags: c#

tengo la  siguiente  linea  de código en la  cual recupero  en un mensaje la Qr , ahora  lo que  intento hacer  es  mediante un lector de  Qr capturarlo   y mostrarlo en un textbox. Gracias  por su ayuda

```
 QRCodeDecoder decoder = new QRCodeDecoder();
 MessageBox.Show(decoder.decode(new QRCodeBitmapImage(picImage.Image as Bitmap)));
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál sería la pregunta? ¿Qué es lo que no está funcionando?

Comment: lo que  quiero hacer es capturarlo mediante  un lector y mostrarlo en  un textbox

Comment: Los lectores de códigos QR no capturan la imagen, funcionan como un teclado. Sería lo mismo que leer el texto ingresado por el usuario. ¿Podrías mostrar el código de lo que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Así como está planteada, no me queda claro qué es lo se quiere preguntar. ¿Estás recibiendo una imagen de algún dispositivo específico o es un lector de QRs normal que funciona como teclado? ¿Cuál es el inconveniente que estás teniendo? ¿Qué intentaste hasta ahora? Te recomendaría leer [ask] y [edit] la pregunta para que quede más claro.

Comment: No acabo de entender bien la pregunta, puede ser que lo que necesitas es obtener el QRCode como imagen en lugar de su texto? Si es así simplemente quédate con: `new QRCodeBitmapImage(picImage.Image as Bitmap)`